# Swift 4: Trim last character of string based on character

Tags: swift

I'm trying to remove the last numbers of an IP address string in Swift so I can loop through IP addresses. For instance if my variable = 192.168.1.123, I would like to trim the string to equal 192.169.1.

I'm not sure how to do this since some IP addresses will end in 1, 2 or 3 digits. I couldn't figure out how to trim back to a certain character.

Answer (score 4):

I have a solution (In your case only). You can try it

```
let str = "192.168.1.123"
var arr = str.components(separatedBy: ".")
arr.removeLast()
let newstr = arr.joined(separator: ".") + "."
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the range of the last `.`:

```
let ip = "192.168.1.123"
let lastdot = ip.range(of: ".", options: .backwards)!
let base = ip[...lastdot.lowerBound]
```

This code assumes there is at least one `.` in the string. If not it will crash. That is easily fixed with proper use of `if let`.

`base` will be a `Substring` so depending on what you do next, you may need to wrap that as:

```
let base = String(ip[...lastdot.lowerBound])
```

Whether explicitly converting to `String` depends on whether subsequent methods require `String` or `StringProtocol`. Converting to `String` copies over the storage again, which is costly and unnecessary for many operations, but may be required in some cases.

Comment: Much faster than splitting and rejoining.

Comment: @BallpointBen I was almost going to agree with you, but a test in Swift Playgrounds shows this to not be true (?!?)  I did 100,000 naive split/rejoin vs. 100,000 `range(of:)` and the split/rejoin performed demonstrably faster: 19 - 20 sec. vs. 30 - 35 sec.

I personally believe `range(of:)` to be the better solution, but I must now hesitate to say its "faster".

Comment: @christopherdrum The playground is a terrible way to do performance tests. I think a better test would be with a simple macOS command line app.

Comment: After testing 10000 iterations of each in a regular Swift file, Quoc's answer runs in 1.17s while rmaddy's runs in 0.092s

Comment: @rmaddy Verified. Wow, the performance differences are huge between Playground and command line app. Didn't expect such a pronounced difference; thought they'd both show at least a common "winner" in such a test.

Comment: @christopherdrum My own tests just showed my code to be about 7x faster than the other code. I built an array of 100,000 random IP strings. Then I did 10 alternations of the two algorithms over the array. The playground is great for quick code tests but not performance for sure.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I see that now. I didn't expect playground to give me "top notch" performance, but I did expect at least "algorithm A is essentially faster than algorithm B". Having `range(of:)` perform 50% slower than the naive split/assemble routine was eye-opening for me today. My own tests in a simple console app showed `range(of:)` to be 7 - 10x faster, as you have corroborated, and as I would have expected. Thanks for the extra diligence.

Comment: Playgrounds are horrible for performance because they implicitly convert everything to `String` so that you can see how the code progressed over time. This means that any tests of performance are meaningless in playgrounds. You actually have to be careful running code with implicitly unwrapped optionals in playgrounds because uninitialized variables may be inadvertently unwrapped in order to be strung.